# how to do customized data search with a (django) RESTful framework API

Tags: json, django, cordova, django-rest-framework

With a RESTful framework, how can I define an API (or APIs) that can return a set of data for a particular search?

For example:
Say, I have 2 models as shown below

```
class Student(models.Model)
  name = ....

class Subject(models.Model)
  title = ....
```

With the Serializer, I can return/create JSON data for both models. But what if I want an API that returns a score for a subject for a particular student?

I could solve this by providing another model and its corresponding serializer.

```
class Score(models.Model)
  student = ForeignKey(Student)
  subject = ForeignKey(Subject)
  score = IntegerField...
```

But the questions is what if I want to do another more "customized" search, say I want to search students who are taller than 170cm? Or I want to know the names of students who study subject Math? Can we use RESTful API to do these operations?

PS: my ultimate aim is to develop mobile apps with Django as the service side and PhoneGap (perhaps with angularjs & Ionic) in the front. I have been searching related tutorials. But I can't find good complete tutorials for beginners. Based on the information I found, I figured that employing RESTful APIs probably produce the best outcome for this develop combination? But the RESTful APIs do not seem to be able to do all the operations/queries. Can anyone advise me if I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into using the Django REST Framework package.  It will allow you to quickly turn your models into APIs and will also add the ability to filter your models via URL query strings.

Here is the documentation for Django REST Framework...
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Take a look at the filtering docs...
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering